# Make page that is almost page-height scrollable

Tags: android, xml, scroll

I have a page that just displays a bunch of data and has a few buttons. It is pretty much static. I want to make the page feel more responsive by giving the page the ability to move around. I know I often just scroll-up when considering a page of data.

I thought I would just surround my page with a scroll view, but that makes there be a small blank strip at the bottom of the screen (as though it is wrapping the content, but I have it set to fill-parent).

Anyway, here is my xml:

```
<ScrollView
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  tools:context=".DealerDetails">

    <LinearLayout       
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#ababab">

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Store" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/distance"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="2 mi." />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">

            <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/DirectionsImage"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:layout_width="0dip"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:contentDescription="@string/CD_Dealer_Location"
               android:src="@drawable/device_access_location_found"
               android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/address1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#2b91af"
                    android:text="555 Super St. Suite 500" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/address2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#2b91af"
                    android:text="San Antonio, TX 78791" /> 
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">

            <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/PhoneImage"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:layout_width="0dip"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:contentDescription="@string/CD_Dealer_Phone_Number"
               android:src="@drawable/device_access_call"
               android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/address1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:text="Sales: " />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/address1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#2b91af"
                        android:text="830-626-5200" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/address1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:text="Service: " />
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/address1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#2b91af"
                        android:text="830-661-4511" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">

            <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/HoursImage"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:layout_width="0dip"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:contentDescription="@string/CD_Dealer_Hours_Of_Operation"
               android:src="@drawable/device_access_time"
               android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ServiceHoursHeader"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:text="Service Hours" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ServiceHoursDetails1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#232323"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:text="Monday-Friday: 8:00 AM - 8:00 PM" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ServiceHoursDetails2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#232323"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:text="Saturday: 8:00 AM - 5:00 PM" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ServiceHoursDetails3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#232323"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:text="Sunday: CLOSED" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">

            <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/HoursImage"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:layout_width="0dip"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:contentDescription="@string/CD_Dealer_Hours_Of_Operation"
               android:src="@drawable/device_access_time"
               android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/SalesHoursHeader"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                    android:text="Sales Hours" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/SalesHoursDetails1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#232323"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:text="Monday-Friday: 8:00 AM - 6:00 PM" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/SalesHoursDetails2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#232323"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:text="Saturday: 8:00 AM - 3:00 PM" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/SalesHoursDetails3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#232323"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:text="Sunday: CLOSED" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp">

            <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/ServicesImage"
               android:layout_weight="1"
               android:layout_width="0dip"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:contentDescription="@string/CD_Dealer_Services_Offered"
               android:src="@drawable/gear"
               android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="241dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ServiceHoursHeader"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:text="Services" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/ServiceHoursDetails1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                    android:text="Body Shop, New Heavy Duty, Used Heavy Sales, Service"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                    android:textColor="#232323" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/MyLocationButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:background="@drawable/dark_button"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="@string/view_inventory"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:onClick="viewInventory" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Sorry about the large block of text, but the important part is likely just the outer-most two elements.

Answer (score 0):

Change your first `LinearLayout` height to `android:layout_height="match_parent"`

Edit: Okay give this a go". Add this to your first `LinearLayout`

```
 android:fillViewport="true"
```

Comment: The issue remains. Just have a very skinny white bar at the bottom of the page and it is not scrollable.

Comment: @PFranchise What user2045570 is trying to suggest is: give your ScrollView the property: `android:fillViewport="true"`. And yes, this will work.

Comment: @user2558882 I added that property, but am still not seeing the desired results. The page is not scrollable.

Comment: @PFranchise `Make page that is almost page-height scrollable` If I understand correctly, page-height is not greater than the screen's height currently. Doesn't that kind of defeat the purpose of using a `ScrollView`? _Even if_ you get it to scroll, what content will be shown?